# Mongodb $geowithin with false

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How can is specify $geoWithin operator with false, where it returns not matching documents?

```
.find({"loc" : { "$geoWithin" : { "$geometry" : { "type" : "Polygon" , "coordinates" : [[[40.125246,-74.327963],[40.125246,-74.325989],[40.123738,-74.325989],[40.123738,-74.327963],[40.125246,-74.327963]]]}}}})
```

I was hoping I could do

```
.find({{"loc" : { "$geoWithin" : { "$geometry" : { "type" : "Polygon" , "coordinates" : [[[40.125246,-74.327963],[40.125246,-74.325989],[40.123738,-74.325989],[40.123738,-74.327963],[40.125246,-74.327963]]]}}}}:false})
```

but that does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As at MongoDB 2.6, there is no support for negation of geospatial queries.

However, you can use two queries to achieve your result. Here's an example in the `mongo` shell:

```
// Find all matching documents
var withinDocs = db.mycollection.find({"loc" : { "$geoWithin" : { ... }}).toArray()

// Convert results into list of _ids for query
var withinIDs = [];
withinDocs.forEach(function (d) {
    withinIDs.push(d._id);
})

// Find documents that do *not* match the geo query using $nin
db.mycollection.find({_id:{$nin:withinIDs}})
```